# How are current generation clock frequencies achieved?

Tags: clock, adc, vlsi

I was recently reading through the design of PLLs and was thinking about how these reference clocks are generated.
We know that the reference is generated from a crystal (Generally Quartz), but the oscillations produced by these crystals top out at 100MHZ, how is this reference multiplied to achieve higher frequencies (GHz)?

Is there a circuit that is used to achieve this? (I'm looking at this from an analog designer's perspective).

Answer (score 0):

Clock can be easily multiplied by 2 using clock trigger at both rising and falling edges. So, clock can get multiplied by 2^n using similar logic.